# Insert text between two marker lines in bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I have some lines stored in a text file called `bashrc_snippet`. I would like to insert them into `.bashrc`. Since I sometimes change the contents of the text file I would like to be able to re-insert them in the .bashrc-file. To do this I want to use marker lines:

```
# User things
HISTSIZE=1000

#START
alias ls='ls --color=tty'
... some more lines
#END
```

I would like a bash script to do this (possibly by using sed or awk). The algoritm should be:

- If the marker lines are missing add them at the end of the file (and the lines of text)
- If the marker lines are present, replace the contents between them with the new lines of text

Comment: Isn't it better to use command "source bashrc_snippet" instead putting the content of the file in your .bashrc?

Comment: Perhaps. But then I need a way to insert the "source bashrc_snippet" into .bashrc and make sure there is only one source-ing. I'm deploying this on many hosts and I don't want to hand edit the .bashrc file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't really understand your requirement, but here's a guess

```
#!/bin/bash

rcfile="$1"
snippet="$2"
var=$(<"$snippet")
if grep -q "START" "$rcfile" ;then
   awk -v v="$var" '/START/ {
     print $0
     print v
     f=1
   }f &&!/END/{next}/END/{f=0}!f' "$rcfile" >t && mv t "$rcfile"
else
   echo "#START" >> "$rcfile"
   echo "$var" >> "$rcfile"
   echo "#END" >> "$rcfile"
fi
```

to use:

```
$  ./test.sh rc_file bashrc_snippet
```

Comment: It looks promising. But there is a small bug: when marker does not exist it writes to the rcFile, but when the marker exist it writes to stdout.

Comment: well, it really isn't too difficult to redirect and rename it. see edit. i/o redirection are really basic stuff in using the shell so you could have easily solved it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest this (ex or vim commands):

```
ex -c '/^#START/+1,/^#END/-1 d' -c '/^#START/ r bashrc_snippet' -c 'wq'
```

Comment: +1 for the answer to what he __wanted__, but the chosen answer should go to @hluk for providing what Lennart __needs__